# Using getUserMedia to get audio from the microphone as it is being recorded?

Tags: audio, webrtc

I'm trying to write a Meteor.JS app that uses peer to peer "radio" communication. When a user presses a button it broadcasts their microphone output to people.

I have some code that gets permission to record audio, and it successfully gets a `MediaStream` object, but I can't figure out how to get the data from the `MediaStream` object as it is being recorded.

I see there is an method defined somewhere for getting all of the tracks of the recorded audio. I'm sure I could find a way to write some kind of loop that notifies me when audio has been added, but it seems like there should be a native, event-driven way to retrieve the audio from `getUserMedia`. Am I missing something? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you will want to do is to access the stream through the AudioAPI(for the recording part). This is after assigning a var to your stream that was grabbed through `getUserMedia` (I call it `localStream`). So, you can create as many MediaStreamsource nodes as you want from one stream, so you can record it WHILE sending it to numerous people through different rtcpeerconnections.

```
var audioContext = new webkitAudioContext() || AudioContext();
var source = audioContext.createMediastreamSource(localStream);
var AudioRecorder = function (source) {
    var recording = false;
    var worker = new Worker(WORKER_PATH);
    var config = {};
    var bufferLen = 4096;
    this.context = source.context;
    this.node = (this.context.createScriptProcessor ||
                 this.context.createJavaScriptNode).call(this.context,
                                                         bufferLen, 2, 2);
    this.node.onaudioprocess = function (e) {
      var sample = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
      //do what you want with the audio Sample, push to a blob or send over a WebSocket
   }
   source.connect(this.node);
   this.node.connect(this.context.destination);
};
```

[Here is a version I wrote/modified](https://github.com/Computician/WebSocketWebRTCRecorders) to send audio over websockets for recording on a server.

For sending the audio only when it is available, you COULD use websockets or a webrtc peerconnection.
You will grab the stream through getUserMedia success object(you should have a global variable that will be the stream for all your connection). And when it becomes available, you can use a signalling server to forward the requesting SDPs to the audio supplier. You can set it the requesting SDPs to receive only and your connection.

1. [PeerConnection example 1](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/WebRTC-PeerConnection.html)
2. [PeerConnection example 2](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/)

Comment: This is some pretty next level stuff, I'm going to work through this and see what I can pull off. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

Try with code like this:

```
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({audio: true, video: false}, 
function(stream) { // Success Callback
    var audioElement = document.createElement("audio");
    document.body.appendChild(audioElement);
    audioElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    audioElement.play();
}, function () {  // Error callback
    console.log("error") 
});
```

You may use the stream from success callback to create a object URL and pass it into an HTML5 audio element.

Fiddle around in http://jsfiddle.net/veritas/2B9Pq/

Comment: Interesting, I'm not sure if this will work with the sharing component of my app but I'll give it a try. Any ideas on how I could **share** audio over the network?

Comment: I think this is hard. Did you maybe try WebRTC API? It's now quite good implemented in browsers. Example: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/ , http://www.webrtc.org/demo